# android:actionBarItemBackground different for ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar

You can change the background of a menu item on the actionbar using the `android:actionBarItemBackground` attribute.

However, this results in the background of menu items in ActionMode having the same color. Is there a way to have different backgrounds for menu items for the normal ActionBar and the ActionMode?

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_mytheme</item>
```

`selectable_background_mytheme`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:actionLayout`, see here: [Android action bar menu item with actionLayout not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908578/android-action-bar-menu-item-with-actionlayout-not-working-properly)

Some other notes:

Your file `"selectable_background_mytheme"` should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:insetLeft="-5dp"
    android:insetRight="-5dp"
    android:insetTop="-5dp" >

    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/stacked_green" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/accent_green" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

i.e. not a selector

Alternatively you could use a bitmap drawable.