# OnMenuItemSelected isn't called when layout is set for menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-inflate

I have a menu which is inflated from main_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/act_sync" 
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/sync_action"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync" />
</menu>
```

and here is the code in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    MyMessageHandler.debug("menu item selected");
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.act_sync:
        sync();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But onOptionsItemSelected is not called when I touch the menu item. When I remove the actionLayout attribute of the menu item, it works fine. How can I fix this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you should use below snippet ( Just for reference )

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        final Menu m = menu;
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.ActionConnection);
        item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                sync();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tested the `item.setOnMenuItemClickListener` but it didn't work. The point was to get my custom view and set clickListener on it. Thanks for your help :) even though, the onClick() should not be annotated by @Override. I edit your response to the version that works, and also is a bit more digest ;)

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I tried setOnMenuItemClickListener, onMenuItemSelected, etc.

Comment: click listener should be on layout i think

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the answer provided by Vipul Shah.

Make sure you disable the clickable option of all items in your action layout:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Otherwise, it may steal the click so that you still cant receive onClick call back.

Comment: Saved my life...!
Without this the answer wouldn't work... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me from killing back pain :)

Comment: Very important. Thank you for this answer. This one + the one from Vipul Shah did it for me...

Comment: Many Thanxxxx, you save my time