# onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) not get called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I am using menu in my activity.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_favourite"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_notification"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/notification_badge"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_favourite:
        inflateFavouriteLayout();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_notification:
        inflateInboxLayout();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have two items in my menu.for that I have two actions favourite and notification. For favourite onOptionItemSelected method gets called but for notification action it dosen't. I used an action layout in notification menuitem. Is that the problem? 
why it is not calling onOptionItemSelected method for notification menu item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so please post Your code from onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: #Opiatefuchs look into edits

Comment: Your opOptionsItemSelected seems to be ok. So please post onCreateOptionsMenu() method and may inly the inflateInboxLayout() methid does not work.

Comment: is this a context menu??

Comment: It works when i remove the line -  android:actionLayout="@layout/notification_badge" from notification menuItem. But with this it dosen't work. So is there a problem with custom layout for menuItem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764821/onmenuitemselected-isnt-called-when-layout-is-set-for-menu-item)

I need to set clicable property as false in my layout which I inflated in menu Item.

```
android:clickable="false"
```